# How to call particular funcion when the check box is checked in plugin options page

Tags: functions, options

I'm new to php and wp plugin development, i just created a simple options page for my test plugin, the options page has only one check box, i don't know how to execute some function when the box is checked,

My plugin options page is like this

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'chec_add_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'chec_settings_init' );


function chec_add_admin_menu(  ) { 

add_options_page( 'Checking', 'Checking', 'manage_options', 'checking', 'checking_options_page' );

}


function chec_settings_init(  ) { 

register_setting( 'my_option', 'chec_settings' );

add_settings_section(
    'chec_checking_section', 
    __( 'Your section description', 'wp' ), 
    'chec_settings_section_callback', 
    'checking'
);

add_settings_field( 
    'chec_checkbox_field_0', 
    __( 'Settings field description', 'wp' ), 
    'chec_checkbox_field_0_render', 
    'checking', 
    'chec_checking_section' 
);


}


function chec_checkbox_field_0_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'chec_settings' );
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='chec_settings[chec_checkbox_field_0]' <?php checked( $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
<?php

}

function chec_settings_section_callback(  ) { 

echo __( 'This section description', 'wp' );

}


function checking_options_page(  ) { 

?>
<form action='options.php' method='post'>

    <h2>Checking</h2>

    <?php
    settings_fields( 'my_option' );
    do_settings_sections( 'checking' );
    submit_button();
    ?>

</form>
<?php

}

?>
```

Now i want to remove wp logo in admin bar when the check box is checked using the following code

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999 );
function remove_wp_logo( $wp_admin_bar ) {
$wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a conditional check to determine if the option is selected, before adding your function to the action hook.

Example:

```
$options = get_option( 'chec_settings' );
if ( $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'] == '1' ) {
    add_action ('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks edwardr for your response, but code you have given is not working, instead i'm getting **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=='**

Comment: Ugh, so sorry, had a parenthesis in the wrong spot. Try the edited code.

Comment: if the check box is checked then wp logo is removed for all user roles, how to execute the function for specific user role if the check box is checked?

Comment: See [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) for a capability conditional.